# Change product attribute for current session / quote

Tags: product-attribute, sessions

Sometimes you want to change a product attribute based on live data.

For example:

Say that there is a product that could come from one of two suppliers (A and B) and when a customer comes to the product page (or list page) my site queries both suppliers to find the cheapest price.

What is the best way to change the product attribute on the fly.

Comment: Do you have any multi-warehouse dropshipper modules in use? And what version of Magento?

Comment: @B00MER no dropship modules are in place...the technical details for this example are...once customer clicks 'buy' we create the order in magento as well as order it by the supplier, if order by supplier fails the order is rolled back automaticaly

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Event
"checkout_cart_product_add_after"
to edit the product in your quote and set the cheaper price or other attributes